# ROS Navigation Package Error

Tags: navigation, ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Raspberry Pi 2 and installed the Ros-Base(Bare bones). After that when I try to install the navigation package (sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-navigation) it downloads everything well but during unpacking it gives the following error :

libqt4-opengl-dev depends on libgles2-mesa-dev
Package libgles2-mesa-dev is not installed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230117/ros-navigation-package-error/) by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2016-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-03-30**:
Please help

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-03-31**:
This sounds relevant: http://askubuntu.com/questions/430684/cannot-install-libgles2-mesa-dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After a lot of research, I found this link and followed it. It then worked for it! You just need to replace the name of your package with package described there and that's it!

Here's the link : http://www.absolutelytech.com/2010/06/30/solved-error-dpkg-error-processing-filename-unpack-trying-to-overwrite/

---

Originally posted by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) with karma: 35 on 2016-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0